# Java 8 Stream Multiple Object Creation from an input File

Tags: java, oop, file-io, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to read a file to capture parameters to be passed to objects using Java 8 stream.

The file format is:

10 AA

15 BB

20 CC

Same number of objects have to be created as the number of lines, the objects take these parameters.

e.g Object a = new Object(10 , AA).

The file will always have a maximum of 3 lines.

I've come as far as reading the file, checking if it starts with a digit, splitting it at new line and placing each line in a List of String[ ].

```
     List<String[]> input = new ArrayList<>();

        try {

          input =  Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\ubaid\\IntelliJ Workspace\\Bakery\\input.txt")).
                    filter(lines->Character.isDigit(lines.trim().charAt(0))).map(x-> x.split("\\r?\\n")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(String a[] : input){
            for(String s : a){
                System.out.println(s);

            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Fureeish: How to create objects using stream and read params from a file. It's already been solved. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have:

```
public class Type {
  private int number;
  private String text;
  // constructor and other methods
}
```

And the file is well formatted:

```
List<Type> objs = Files.lines(path)
    .map(s -> s.split(" "))
    .map(arr -> new Type(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), arr[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(objs);
```

Comment: Or `s.split(" ", 2)`, so it doesn’t search for additional occurrences of the delimiter.